# Rename Google Drive files from sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I am looking for a script that loops through a google sheet and renames the files in a folder on google drive.

The sheet has the location of the file in drive and the name of the original file and the new name of the file.

Since I am a complete beginner at google script and javascript i would be enternal grateful if someone could help me with this.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/

Comment: What specific issue are you having? Being "a complete beginner" simply means that you need to spend time learning - it doesn't mean we have to do anything for you.

Answer (score 3):

## Rename All of the Files in a Folder

### From data in a Spreadsheet

I didn't have anything to do so I thought I'd give it a try.  I only tested it once and it doesn't interact with the user.  So here it is.

```
function renameFiles(shname){
  //var shname=shname||'bullSheet';
  if(shname){
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sh=ss.getSheetByName(shname);
    var rg=sh.getDataRange();
    var vA=rg.getValues();
    var folderId=getFolderId(shname);
    if(vA.length>2){
      var nameA=[];
      var idA=[];
      var fldr=DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
      var files=fldr.getFiles();
      while(files.hasNext()){
        var file=files.next();
        nameA.push(file.getName());
        idA.push(file.getId());
      }
      for(var i=2;i<vA.length;i++){
        var idx=nameA.indexOf(vA[i][0]);
        if(!vA[i][2] && vA[i][1] && vA[i][0] && idx>-1){
          DriveApp.getFileById(idA[idx]).setName(vA[i][1]);
          vA[i][2]='RENAMED';
        }
      }
      rg.setValues(vA);
    }else{
      var fA=[];
      var fldr=DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
      var files=fldr.getFiles();
      while(files.hasNext()){
        var file=files.next();
        sh.appendRow([file.getName()]);
      }
    }
  }
}


function getFolderId(shname){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName(shname);
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  return vA[0][1];
}
```

Here's the spreadsheet when you start. It has the folder id in B1 and three headers on line 2 and nothing else.

[image]

Then you run renameFiles the first time and it reads the files in the directory whose id is in B2 and puts them on the spreadsheet.

[image]

Then you enter the new names for these files in column 2 under the headers.

[image]

Then run the program again and it renames the files to your new names and puts "RENAMED" in column 3 which keeps the program from doing anything if you run it again.

[image]

There's still quite a bit that you might wish to add like dialogs that tell the user what's going on but I'll leave that as an exercise for you.

> If you have a lot of files in a directory you may have to add page tokening to the process.  I chose not to do that because I'm basically lazy.
>
> If your wondering where to get the folder id then go to the folder in google drive and look at the url.  It's the longest section in the url

Comment: That first `if` test will always be true since you add a default value.